# Как изменить объект на нужном разрешении экрана?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имеется график, который при разрешении экрана больше 1020px, должен иметь высоту 420px. При разрешении меньше 1020 он должен "сохраняет оригинальное соотношение пикселей" за это отвечает maintainAspectRatio. Но как мне сделать чтобы это параметр переключался из false in true при изменении размера экрана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#d1d1d1';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = '16';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Montserrat';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'bold';
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line',

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", ''],

    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: '#FDE52C',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#FDE52C',
        borderWidth: 3,
        data: [10, 30, 34, 36, 37, 34],
      },
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: '#002E5B',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#002E5B',
        borderWidth: 3,
        data: [10, 20, 30, 34, 42, 50],
      }
    ]
  },

  options: {
    responsive: true,
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 1,
    maintainAspectRatio: true, // Вот этот нужно переключить
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 10,
          max: 50,
          stepSize: 10
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0.000001
      },
      point: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0
      }
    }
  }

});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  let viewport = screen.width;
  if (viewport < 1020) {
    chart.options.maintainAspectRatio = true;
  } else {
    chart.options.maintainAspectRatio = false;
  }

  console.log(chart.options.maintainAspectRatio);
});
```

```css
.global-assets__chart {
  width: 50%;
}

.global-assets .chart {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 420px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .global-assets .chart {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="global-assets__chart d-flex align-end">
  <div class="chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!!!

Comment: Рад помочь, и за одно навыки нарабатываю

Comment: @Netahaki так оно ж не фурычит, там ещё адаптивность вырубить надо в настройках. + изначально чтоб график был 440. Без отключения адаптивности высота графика не поменяется и.т.д. Проверь сам.)

Comment: Работает в codepen

Answer (score 0):

Использователь событие resize. Переделал [Codepen](https://codepen.io/JekaVorobev/pen/bjeVWL?editors=1111)

```js
$(function(){
  var graf = $('#myChart'); // Сам график
  console.log($(window).width());
  $(window).width() > 1200 ? graf.height('440') : ''
    $(window).on('resize',function(){     
        if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
            chart.options.maintainAspectRatio = false;
             graf.height('440'); // Начальное значение высоты
        } else {
            chart.options.maintainAspectRatio = true;
        }
      console.log(chart.options.maintainAspectRatio)
    })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: подключать `jquery` ради трех строчек?)

Comment: https://codepen.io/Derzhavin_Vlad/pen/rrLary
Не получается(

Comment: @ThisMan он скорее всего и так подключен

Comment: @АнтонФедоров Переделал. Смотрите.